# The decimal point appears as a triangle in inkscape

Tags: matplotlib, inkscape

I am using Inkscape to merge two figures. One of the figures, created using matplotlib, has a mathematical text written over it. To the best of my understanding, the text is rendered using latex by matplotlib. When I import this figure in Inkscape, the decimal points in the text are replaced automatically by small triangles. What could be done? Please have a look at the following image. Thanks in advance. 
[image]

**Edit:** Here is an example to produce a similar plot which when imported in inkscape, renders a wrong font.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 9])
plt.annotate(r'$\alpha = 2.4$', xy = (0.1, 0.9), xycoords = 'axes fraction')
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('test.pdf', bbox_inches = 'tight')
```

Comment: *"To the best of my understanding.."*; That's a setting in either your `matplotlibrc` file (`text.usetex`) or `rcParams`.

Comment: Thanks. How do I handle it to render the decimal point properly?

Comment: The comment by @Bart was meant for you to check if or if not you are using latex, i.e. is `print(plt.rcParam["text.usetex"])` true or false? This is important here, so include that in the question. Next, you would want to make this as reproducible as possible for others (because usually people see decimal points where they should be, so something must be special here).

Comment: Well this gives me `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'rcParam'`. I am on Ubuntu 14 which is somewhat old version. Could that be the problem here?

Comment: That should be `plt.rcParams["text.usetex"]` (with an *s* after Param)

Comment: Hmm. This gives me `False`. What is happening?

Comment: `False` is good, it means you are not using latex, which may simplify things. Still, you need to provide a [mcve]. You may also look at what font is used.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have added a minimal example to produce a plot. Please have a look.

Comment: Ok, so there is nothing special with your code and it does produce the [correct picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ps1ye.png) for me when importing into inkscape. It seems rather unusual to save as pdf and then *import* into inkscape. What happens if you save as svg, `plt.savefig('test.svg'..)` and then *open* in inkscape? Also, what font are you using? The default should be Deja Vu Sans. Can you check if this is the case for you (double click as often as you need on the text in inkscape until you can select the text). Is this the same font as used in matplotlib?

Comment: I forgot to mention that if I import other formats like eps or svg, everything looks fine. So that is a workaround. However, I would really like to import pdf.